# why transition property not added in image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-router

I am trying to slide my next image from `right to left` when I click on `next button` and `left to right` when click `previous` button
here is my code
why transition property not added in image  ?

I tried to add `transition` property  to all element started  from `div` ,`li` ,'img' but none of them work

```
.imageSlider ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  width :325px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
   transition: width 2s;
}

.imageSlider ul li img{
    transition: all 1s ease;
   transition: width 2s;
}

.imageSlider {
  width :325px;
  overflow:hidden
  transition: width 2s;
   position:relative;
}
```

On button click I do this.

```
next(){
    var current = this.state.currentSlide;
    var next = current + 1;
    if (next > this.props.stories.items.length - 1) {
      next = 0;
    }
   this.setState({
  currentSlide: next
});
    console.log(this.state.currentSlide ,"next---")

  }
  pre(){
    var current = this.state.currentSlide;
    var prev = current - 1;
    if (prev < 0) {
      prev = this.props.stories.items.length - 1;
    }
   this.setState({
  currentSlide: prev
});
```

any update 
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/g5wl3vBRl

Comment: could you share the html ?

Comment: sorry forgot to share code https://codesandbox.io/s/g5wl3vBRl